# Phone tethered to laptop for internet and then send internet out wirelessly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

What I am looking for is a way to take the internet I have available on my laptop (from using my tethered smart phone) and project that out just like a wireless router would from a modem.  This way all wifi enabled devices can connect no problem.

I have done ad hoc networks to share my internet connection on my tethered laptop but not everything works like a proper wireless router would.

Laptops, phones, and tablets can connect and use the signal but my Nintendo Wii and Sony entertainment player do not.

I assume wireless TVs, printers, Chromecast (etc) will have the same issue.  The peer to peer connection of a ad hoc network won't do this. The Wii actually can discover the network when searching but unable to connect.  I need something that mimics what a router does and provides that wireless access point.

[http://www.amazon.com/TP-LINK-TL-WR702N-Wireless-Repeater-150Mpbs/dp/B007PTCFFW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007PTCFFW)
This is the closest I've come but from what I've read, and I did call the company, it will not work.  Any ideas?  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe bridge mode on that device?  I wonder if it could take the ad hoc signal and re-transmit as a wireless access point.

Comment: Or maybe the regular AP mode of the device would work. http://www.tp-link.com/en/article/?id=393  If a wired ethernet connection from the wall will work into the router wouldn't an ethernet connection from my laptop do the same?  From reading I know I can connect my laptop directly into gaming systems (Xbox, PS3, Wii) and share it, but will this wireless router do the same?

Answer (score 0):

> (from using my tethered smart phone)

I don't know the specs of your phone, so I'm going out on a bit of a limb, but I'd think it'd be easier to use your phone to broadcast as a wireless AP, than to configure those services on your PC.

Android, for instance, has wifi AP tether apps that will broadcast an SSID with configurable options. I use one called 'wifi tether router' and successfully connected my laptop and tablet to it. Anytime I'm in the datacenter, I use this method for inet access back to the office.

Multiple devices attached may/could cause performance issues, but the core services like DHCP/DNS/Routing are all taken care of for you.

Comment: I can attest to this. I've seen a good number of phones fail to see ad-hoc wireless networks.